# Paypal URLs not working properly

Tags: php, url, paypal

I'm trying to redirect users to Paypal to make a payment but instead the usual html form I wrote this code (I need the form to submit data to my site, then I redirect to Paypal)

```
    ($sandbox) ? $url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" : $url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    ($sandbox) ? $button = "XXXXX" : $button = "YYYYY";

    $notify_url = urlencode($site_url . "index.php?act=member-pn&mid=" . $ld['member_id']);
    $return_url = urlencode($site_url . "index.php?act=member-ps");
    $cancel_url = urlencode($site_url . "index.php?act=member-pc&mid=" . $ld['member_id']);

    $url .= "/?notify_url=$notify_url&return=$return_url&cancel_return=$cancel_url&cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=$button";

    header("Location: $url");
```

Why is it that only the cancel URL is working? Return and notify doesn't seems to work.

Comment: where are you testing these? is it at your localhost ?

Comment: have you tried echoing url? are the values correct?

Comment: everything is correct, now I got the return URL to work too, it seems that it needs to be something simple like site.com/success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ...the answer to my question is simple: always remember if you have htaccess authentication for the site you are working on. Paypal's IPN never got a chance to access my scripts :)

And, yes, you can do a GET requests for a simple button instead of POST.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to send the values as POST request. Looks like you are doing a GET request from the code.

As for the notify_url and return_url I'm assuming those features are already enabled in your Paypal account.

A possible solution, is that you can capture the form submit using jQuery Validate (for example) and then send that the initial data to your server to register your user and then once that's finished you can submit the form to paypal.

Comment: Those features are disabled in my paypal account. If it needs to be a POST request why does the cancel URL work?

Comment: Think Gohn is right, you aren't posting the paypal site, the get might partial work but I would try POSTing the data first

Comment: I can't POST to paypal, I need the form to POST to my server to register the user first then redirect to paypal

Comment: Hmm, have you tried sending ajax request on submit to your server and then after that gets process sending the post request to paypal? I think I did that before on a site I worked on once.

Answer (score 0):

we made something very simmilar a few days ago. we thought about ajax and jquery....
but now we are using 2 forms, it's the easiest way.
user klicks on checkout in the shop (1. form) -> post to our server -> we save in db -> user klicks on "pay with paypal"  (2. form) -> gets redirectet to paypal -> pays -> our server gets the confirmation -> our server sends confirmation to shop

what about this way?

Comment: yep, but that's a two step process